# Webkit CSS - Selector to Change Color of Highlight

Tags: css, webkit, highlight

I noticed a cool effect in Chrome at [***this site***](http://www.houseoffraser.co.uk/Aquascutum+Pritchard+performance+jacket/149715211,default,pd.html), which may or may not be unique to Chrome but possibly for all Webkit browsers.

When the user drags to highlight something, they've changed the default color to pink.

Can you identify the selector?

I would like to see if someone knows of a reference page which describes these kinds of effects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use

```css
::-moz-selection,
::selection{
    background: #fe57a1;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

from [HTML5 BoilerPlate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: Note to OP - This one allows it to work in Firefox, as well as the Webkit browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the link and solution, nice to ask a quick and simple question for once

Comment: Also note that you cannot combine the two selectors otherwise it'll fail. Meaning, ::selection, ::-moz-selection { ... } won't work.

Comment: One more note: this only works for text in paragraphs (<p>). This does not work for <div>s.

Comment: @Mark how comes? http://jsbin.com/qanagenuqa/1/edit - for me it works.. at least in Chrome

Comment: @ZoltanToth Seems to be a problem when the element contains text and child nodes. Here it does not work in the first line: http://jsbin.com/vikukobede/1/ (latest Safari)

Answer (score 2):

I found this CSS in that page:

```css
::selection {
  background: #E02F86;
  color: white;
}
```

Also, tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/E6b24/).